# Let $A$ be a $6 \times 6$ rank one matrix, find all possible Jordan canonical forms of A. The order of Jordan blocks should be ignored

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $6 \times 6$ rank one matrix, find all possible Jordan canonical forms of A. The order of Jordan blocks should be ignored.

We know that $A=uv^{t}$, because $A$ is rank one. So, each column of $A$ is a scalar multiple of a specific column in $A$. Moreover, the minimal polynomial is $m(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-v^{t}u)$. We know that the only two possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $v^tu$. Also, I think that $\lambda=0$ has multiplicity at least $5$. So, the block size corresponding to  $\lambda= v^tu$ is at most $1$.

This what I have so far.

\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & v^tu 
\end{bmatrix}

I am having trouble finding any other matrices. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $v^Tu$ with $\alpha\not= 0$ and you obtain the entire set of solutions.